# Eclipse plugin doesn't work on Macs

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-plugin, text-editor

I'm building a plugin in Eclipse 3.5 on Windows which is a text editor for a language that my group works with. I distributed it as a .jar and just had people place it in the dropins folder. The problem is it doesn't run on any of the Macs that my coworkers use, but it seems to work fine on PCs. When run on a Mac, the plugin is simply not detected by Eclipse. No errors are generated as far as I can tell, I've checked the log files and run Eclipse in debug mode with no results. I've also tried -clean with no success. It's as if the file's not even there.

I'm brand-new to Eclipse and Eclipse plugin development, so I did some googling and found out about the Delta Packs, so I installed the one for my version and retargeted my plugin.  Even after that we get the same result on the Mac -> no result at all. Since I have to bug a coworker every time I want to try something I haven't checked the error logs after trying the Delta Pack'd version. There are no platform filters specified, and all versions of Eclipse are set to use Java 1.6. Any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you load Eclipse, does anything appear in the Error log view? (rather than the log file) (Make sure to clear it first. (Window->Show view->Error log). I'm trying to figure out if it's really not detected or there's a loading error. The Mac version of Eclipse is the bastard child nobody cares for, I'v had similar experiences.

Comment: I finally got it working, it seems that it was a combination of the issue that Fabian discussed and the fact that the Mac I was doing most of my testing on was running Eclipse 3.4 and was encountering the SWT/Carbon issue, which was fixed with the Cocoa transition in 3.5. The plugin works on a Mac when compiled for Java 5 and run on Eclipse 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue recently with a plug-in developed under Java 6 on Windows. I had to change the execution environment of the plug-in (in the manifest file) and the project JRE to Java 5 to have it show up on my Mac.

Now my Mac only has Java 5. You are saying these Macs have Java 6. Still it is quite probable Eclipse itself is running on Java 5, as I believe only the Eclipse 3.5 *64-bit* version will run on Java 6 on the Mac, and even then probably not by default.

Comment: What's the best way to go about changing the project JRE? I tried changing the entire workspace over to 5 and replacing 6 with 5 in the individual project's build path, but it still didn't work on the Mac we tried.

Comment: What I did was to set up the execution environment in the manifest and then apply the quick fix (ctrl-1) on the warning I got in the text tab of the manifest editor (something like 'fix project classpath setup', the warning was something like 'project JRE is not a perfect match for the execution environment').

Answer (score 0):

It could be execution environment as Fabian suggests. Also check that the plugin doesn't explicit specify an OS. I accidentally set that in a plugin once. Most of the time it's not needed unless there is a native library dependency.